# Error returned on newsletter sign-up via profiles in Wordpress

Tags: newsletter

we are collecting email addresses for our newsletter via a profile sign-up on our website, where it is embedded as an iframe (no way around this).

This has worked fine until some recent update either from civi or Wordpress, which I cannot say for sure. However, addresses are still recorded but after submission, this is error message is returned: 
"Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred.
We can't load the requested web page. This page requires cookies to be enabled in your browser settings. Please check this setting and enable cookies (if they are not enabled). Then try again. If this error persists, contact the site administrator for assistance."

I have played around with the paths while trying to fix the issue but had no success. I made the following findings:

- It used to work before in the same setting.
- If the e-mail address already exist, there is an message stated saying that it is a duplicate and the abovementioned error doesnt show.
- It works correctly if i am a signed-in in the Wordpress backend while signing up.

  - Our event registration works fine with the same setup.

Do you have any ideas or suggestions how to fix this?

Thank you in advance!
Dennis

Answer (score 0):

Since this works when you are logged into WordPress it looks like it might be a permissions issue. Is the redirect after submission set in the profile advanced settings? You may want to check the page being redirected to to make sure anonymous users have access to it. Also check the permissions for anonymous users under 'Administer>Users and Permissions>Permissions (access control)' click on WordPress Access Control. Particularly the permissions around profiles.

What version of  WordPress & CiviCRM are you running? Since it was working OK prior to recent updates when was your last CiviCRM update?

Hope this helps.